# Drupal 7 Multiple sites under subdirectories in server root?

Tags: drupal, dns, drupal-7

I have a drupal installation in root/httpdocs and want to make a copy of it for development purposes in root/testsite. I have created the folder, copied the website files from httpdocs to testsite and setup a domain pointing to that folder. However, when I visit the page I get "This webpage is not available".
When I try to ping it, I get "unknown host".

Can anyone point to the problem? .htaccess? dns?

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple virtual hosts.

If your using a localhost see: [Creating Multiple Virtual Sites on a WAMP Server Installation](http://www.trailheadinteractive.com/creating_multiple_virtual_sites_a_single_apache_install_windows_xp)

Or for a Debian solution see: [Hosting multiple websites with Apache2](https://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412)